# Find the start and end of a word in a string using index of

Tags: c#, indexof

I have 2 strings. I ut each charcter into a list using a foreach loop. I then use a for loop to go through each character in the 2 lists to see if there is a difference. Once I find a difference between the strings I want to find the start and end of that word that has changed eg. `String1` is different to `String2` I want the output to be "`String1 String2 is the first second string"`. I plan on finding the start and end of the changed word using `indexOf` and at the moment it's not finding the position of the index.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const string a = "String1 is the first string";
        const string b = "String2 is the second string";
        List<String> listString1 = new List<string>();
        List<String> listString2 = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            listString1.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var item in b)
        {
            listString2.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            var or = listString1[i];
            var ed = listString2[i];

            int nextSpace = or.IndexOf(' ', index);
            int previousSpace = or.LastIndexOf(' ', index);
            if (or!=ed)


            {

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you should use the debugger and step through your code.. just looking at your first 2 foreach loops and then looking at your for loop, you will never accomplish finding the beginning and ending string.. look into string.Split() function for starters

Comment: I am stepping through my code and it's doing exactly what I want it to do which is go through each letter in the string and find if any character is changed. If it has then I want to find the full word where the character has changed e.g. String1 and String2 are different so I now want to display the 2 words that are different.

Comment: @CraigGallagher this is assuming that the strings you are comparing will be the exact same in length, and the only difference between them will be a different word/letter?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Yes that is the case it needs to find the difference in a word or letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I am confused about what you're trying to achieve.  But maybe I am on the right path with what I am providing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string firstString = "I am the first string";
    string secondString = "I am the second string";

    char delimiter = Convert.ToChar(" ");

    if (firstString.Equals(secondString))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Both strings are equal");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        var firstStringList = firstString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

        // ["I", "am", "the", "first", "string"]

        var secondStringList = secondString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

        // ["I", "am", "the", "second", "string"]

        foreach (var word in firstStringList)
        {
            if (secondStringList.IndexOf(word) == -1)
            {
                var indexOfWord = firstStringList.IndexOf(word); // 3
                secondStringList.Insert(indexOfWord, word); // Insert the word that was not found at position 3 inside secondStringList
                // ["I", "am", "the", "first", "second", "string"]
                // [ 0,    1,    2,      3,        4,         5  ]
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", secondStringList));
                // Join the secondStringList to make 1 string separated by the space character
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code will split the first string & second string into lists of strings containing the words that make up the strings.. then will loop through the first string list and compare each word within that list to the words in the second string list.. once it finds the word in the first string that does not exist in the second string.. it will print that word.

Again, not sure of the goal of this, but let me know based on what I posted what needs to be tailored.

Comment: The reason I was going through each charterer in the string was because once I found a difference in a letter in the second string I wanted to add that word to my first string right after where the word changed so something like this "I am the first second string" do you get what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: You're a legand

Answer (score 0):

Basic happy-path solution..

```
string newString = "";

string[] as1 = "String1 is the first string".Split(new char[] { ' ' });
string[] as2 = "String2 is the second string".Split(new char[] { ' ' });

for (int ndx = 0; ndx < as1.Length; ndx++)
{
    newString += (as1[ndx] == as2[ndx]) ? as1[ndx] : as1[ndx] + ' ' + as2[ndx];
    newString += ' ';
}
```

You need bounds checking on the arrays at least. But I'm not going to do all your homework for you :)